# Questions about $eAe$-modules.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra, $e$ be an idempotent, and $M$ be a right $A$-module. Let $f_M: \operatorname{Hom}_A(eA, M) \to Me$ be the map defined by $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(e)e$ for $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(eA, M)$. We can show that $f_M$ is an isomorphism of right $eAe$-modules. By this result, take $M=eA$, we have $\operatorname{End}(eA)$ is isomorphic to $eAe$. It is said that the isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(eA) \to eAe$ induces an isomorphism of $K$-algebras. How to understand this? Is $\operatorname{End}(eA)$ isomorphic to $eAe$ as $K$-algebras? How to show that $f_M$ is functorial at $M$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two questions in there:

> 1. Is $f_{eA}:\operatorname{End}(eA)\to eAe$ an isomorphism of $K$-algebras?
> 2. Is $f_M$ functorial?

Let me answer them separately:

1. So I think you believe that $f_{eA}$ is bijective (as it is an isomorphism of right $eAe$-modules). So we just have to prove that it is compatible with multiplication. The multiplication in $\operatorname{End}(eA)$ is composition, the multiplication in $eAe$ is just the restriction of the multiplication in $A$. So we have to prove that $f_{eA}(\varphi)\cdot f_{eA}(\psi)=f_{eA}(\varphi\circ \psi)$. By definition the left hand side is equal to $\varphi(e)e\cdot \psi(e)e$. Now the right hand side is $(\varphi\circ \psi)(e)\cdot e=\varphi(\psi(e))e$. Now since $\psi(e)\in eA$ we have $\psi(e)=e\psi(e)$, hence $$\varphi(\psi(e))e=\varphi(e\psi(e))e=\varphi(e)\psi(e)e,$$ where the last equality comes from the fact that $\psi(e)$ is an element of $A$ and $\varphi$ is a right $A$-module homomorphism. Now we can apply again $\psi(e)=e\psi(e)$ to get that the left hand side equals the right hand side.
2. For the functoriality consider the following diagram for a right $A$-module homomorphism $r:M\to N$:
   $$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
   \newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
   \newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
   \begin{array}{c}
   \operatorname{Hom}(eA,M) & \ra{f_M} & Me  \\
   \da{r\circ -} & & \da{r|_{Me}} \\
   \operatorname{Hom}(eA,N) & \ras{f_N} & Ne \\
   \end{array}$$
   So let $\varphi\in \operatorname{Hom}(eA,M)$. If you go first right then down you end up with $r(\varphi(e)e)$ and if you go first down then right you end up with $(r\circ \varphi)(e)e$. That both expressions are equal follows immediately from the fact that $r$ is a right $A$-module homomorphism.

Comment: thank you very much. In the book [Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), it is said that $\varphi(e)=\varphi(e)e$ (page 19, line 5 of Lemma 4.2). Is this true? I think that maybe $\varphi(e) \neq \varphi(e)e$.

Comment: This is true since $\varphi$ is a right $A$-module homomorphism and $e$ is an idempotent. Hence $\varphi(e)=\varphi(e^2)=\varphi(e)e$.