Why $eAe$ is identical with $\mathrm{End}(eA)$
Let $A$ be an algebra and $e$ is an (maybe full) idempotent.
I saw there is an isomophism between $eAe$ and $\mathrm{End}(eA)$. How is it constructed？

See lemma 1,6 p. 8 of this document.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325436.

See as well here.

There is no need for $e$ to be full.  The isomorphism from $eRe$ to $End(eR_R)$ is pretty much the first one you'd think of: left multiplication by elements of $eRe$.

Related: $Hom(fR, eR)\cong eRf$ as Abelian groups (no ring structure.)
